# Spyne in_protocol Soap11 and http headers

Tags: nginx, http-headers, spyne

I can't handle http and https headers in Spyne.
I have NginX + Twisted + Spyne, It works well, but I need to get userId for filter functionality in Spyne. May be I should dig somewhere else?

The code is:
Client:

```
url_service = 'http://localhost:8000/?wsdl'
client = suds.client.Client(url_service)
client.set_options(headers={'ee': 'we'}, username = 'login')
w = client.service.get_head('neo')
print w
```

Server:

```
import logging
import random
import sys
import base64

from spyne.application import Application
from spyne.decorator import rpc
from spyne.error import ResourceNotFoundError
from spyne.model.complex import ComplexModel
from spyne.model.fault import Fault
from spyne.model.primitive import Mandatory
from spyne.model.primitive import String
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from spyne.service import ServiceBase

from twisted.internet import reactor 
from twisted.web.server import Site 
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource 
from twisted.python import log 

class RequestHeader(ComplexModel):
    __tns__ = 'spyne.examples.authentication'
    username = unicode()
    ee = unicode()

class UserService(ServiceBase):
    __tns__ = 'spyne.examples.authentication'
    __in_header__ = RequestHeader

    @rpc(Mandatory.String, _returns=String)
    def get_head(ctx, user_name):
        print '*'*20
        print ctx.in_header_doc
        print ctx.in_body_doc
        print ctx.in_header.ee
        retval = "Where's the header"
        return retval

def _on_method_call(ctx):
    return

UserService.event_manager.add_listener('method_call', _on_method_call)

HOST = '127.0.0.1' 
PORT = 8000 

if __name__=='__main__':
    from spyne.util.wsgi_wrapper import run_twisted

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('twisted').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    application = Application([UserService],
        tns='spyne.examples.authentication',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
        out_protocol=Soap11()
    )

    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)

    resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor, wsgi_app) 
    site = Site(resource) 
    reactor.listenTCP(PORT, site, interface=HOST) 

    logging.info("listening to http://127.0.0.1:8000")
    logging.info("wsdl is at: http://localhost:8000/?wsdl")
    sys.exit(reactor.run())
```

error:

```
ERROR:spyne.application.server:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ee'
```

Thanx in Advance, Yury

Answer (score 1):

When your in_protocol is SOAP, `ctx.in_headers` are for soap headers. If you want to inspect HTTP headers, you actually need to look at the transport headers.

As every transport has its own way of handling things, these will be mostly transport specific. In case of Twisted HTTP, you need to get hold of the Request object from Twisted's HTTP package.

You can use `ctx.transport.req` to get hold of that object.

As for extracting headers from that, you need to consult the Twisted docs.

Here is the relevant page for your convenience:

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.http.Request.html

Comment: Hello! `(ctx.transport.req['HTTP_EE']` helped to get headers, but still can't get username and password

Comment: So if the information you're looking for is not in HTTP headers, SOAP headers, HTTP body or SOAP body, where is it?

Comment: FWIW, suds doesn't seem to support a `username` kwarg passed to `set_options`. See: https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.options.Options-class.html

Comment: Hello, Burak! I use this SUDS connection to get authenticated, so it passes kw username and password successfully, Also I found getuser and getpassword in Twisted class, but, as request is wrapped in Spyne, can't use function with spyne request object - it throws an error.. As for now we decided to move username and password to http header in nginx proxy, but I don't feel comfortable with this solvation.

Comment: Can't do any other apporaches, decided to leave it in nginx, but last attempt was in Suds: `t = HttpAuthenticated(username='usernameq333', password='passworde333')
url_service = 'http://localhost:8000/?wsdl'
client = suds.client.Client(url_service, transport = t)`, this way in Spyne I can read `HTTP_AUTHENTICATION` param with user:password in base64 string. at least it is passed.. but from SOAPUI this param  is not passed.

Comment: Probaly nginx is terminating http basic auth and doesn't pass authentication headers down to Spyne but it's not possible for me to guess without more information.